# Push Values Onto a Vector in a Control Loop

Tags: matlab, vector, octave

In MATLAB is there a way to define a variable say *runningValue* and push values onto it in succession an unknown number of times?

What I have been doing is something like this:

```
runningValue = 0;
for j=1:length(someVector)
    ...
    runningValue(end+1) = (some value);
    ...
endfor
```

But this forces a leading 0.  I know that after all is done I could just put *j(1) = [];* but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this.

Note that the length of the *runningValue* variable is not a priori known; in particular, we are not populating *length(someVector)* elements, referring to the pseudocode above, and the *j* index is no of use.

Comment: `runningValue = [];` maybe for the initialization?

Comment: Didn't know you could do that - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from initializing runningValue to empty, you might as well try reducing the number of appendition, which is an O(n) operation. Instead of appending an element on every loop, you can double the size of the array when it is full. This way, you reduce the number of appendition from n to log(n):

```
runningValue = [];
len = 0;
for j = 1:n
  if (j > len) 
    runningValue = [runningValue zeros(size(runningValue))];
    len = length(runningValue);
  end
  runningValue(j) = (some value);
end
runningValue(j+1:len) = []; % If you need to remove the extra zeros
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply construct a new vector using an existing vector plus another element:

```
runningValue = [];
for j=1:5
    runningValue = [runningValue i]; % i can be the element you want to append to the vector
end
```

This code will output:

```
runningValue =

   1   2   3   4   5
```